# Limit inserts to 6 rows per id

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, plsql

I am learning Hibernate creating a basic console app, using Oracle as the back end. I have a table where if a student enters a 7th record he should not be permitted to do so. How do I do this?

Comment: You would need a trigger to limit the number of rows that are inserted per user.

Comment: Presumably there is a column on your table which identifies the Student?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It would be interesting to see what kind of trigger you have in mind. There may be a way to use triggers for this, but any solution will necessarily be complicated and inefficient. Think about "mutating table" problems first, before you suggest something.

Comment: Do you mean each student using the database is limited to 6 inserts, or do you mean each student ID can appear up to 6 times in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Well beside triggers, you can create a materialized view , then a checking constraint on the table.

```
create materialized view log on test_table;

create materialized view mv_test_table
 refresh FAST on COMMIT
 ENABLE QUERY REWRITE 

as
  select id, count(*) cnts
    from test_table
   group by id;

alter table test_table
  add constraint check_userid
  check (cnts< 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple trigger (on condition that your table has an ID column):

```
create or replace trigger trg_limit_row
after insert on your_table
for each row
begin
  if :new.id >5 then -- assume that you have id in range (0-5) -> 6 rows
    execute immediate 'delete from your_table t where t.id = ' 
    || ':' || 'new_id';
  end if;
end;
/
```